# Logstash : Aggregate exception occurred. TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: logstash

I am getting this Type conversion error :no implicit conversion of String into Integer
I have no clue what could be the reason for that.

I have multiple input fields from sql (including string, integer and decimal) to my Filter. Here is my filter aggreagtion :

```
filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{providerid}"
       code => "
            map['providerid'] ||= event.get('providerid')
            map['pricingbytrade'] ||= []
            kpishistorical = {}
            kpiscurrent = {}
            hash = event.to_hash
            hash.each { |key,value|
                if key != 'providerid' && key != 'cbsaid' && key != 'primarytrade' && key != 'cbsapricingscore' && key != 'cbsaname' && key != 'scoreyear' && key != 'type'  && !key.include?('@') && key != 'historicalcbsapricingscore' && !key.start_with?('current')
                    if value.is_a? Numeric
                        value = value.to_f
                    end
                    kpishistorical.store(key, value)
                end
                if key != 'providerid' && key != 'cbsaid' && key != 'primarytrade' && key != 'cbsapricingscore' && key != 'cbsaname' && key != 'scoreyear' && key != 'type'  && !key.include?('@') && !key.start_with?('historical')
                    if value.is_a? Numeric
                        value = value.to_f
                    end
                    kpiscurrent.store(key, value)
                end
            }

           map['pricingbytrade'].find {|m| m['name'] == event.get('primarytrade')}['pricingbycbsa'] <<
                    {
                        'cbsaid' => event.get('cbsaid'),
                        'cbsaname' => event.get('cbsaname'),
                        'pricingscore' => event.get('cbsapricingscore'),
                        'kpis' => kpiscurrent,
                        'historical' => [
                            {
                                'scoremonth' => event.get('scoremonth'),
                                'scoreyear' => event.get('scoreyear'),
                                'pricingscore' => event.get('historicalcbsapricingscore'),
                                'kpis' => kpishistorical
                            }
                        ]
                    }
     event.cancel()
    "
  }
}
```

here cbsapricingscore and historicalcbsapricingscore are decimal input  and cbsaid is integer input to filter.

Can someone help solve this error?

Comment: Without seeing the structure of an event it is hard to say, but I most often see that error when indexing into an array using a field that is a string.

Comment: thank you for the reply @Badger. I re-wrote the last aggregate part with different condition and it started to work now. Still not sure what was the problem with this code.